# Counter-example to $\{\omega\in\Omega|f(\omega)=g(\omega)\}$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

If $(\Omega,\sigma)$ and $(\Omega',\sigma')$ are sets with a sigma-algebras, if $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions $(\Omega,\sigma)\rightarrow(\Omega',\sigma')$, can one give a counter-example to the fact that $\{\omega\in\Omega|f(\omega)=g(\omega)\}$ is in $\sigma$ ?

If $(\Omega',\sigma')=(X,\mathcal{B}(X))$ with X being a topological vector space in which $\{0\}$ is closed, then this is true, because $f-g$ is measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\Omega = \Omega' = \mathbb{N}$ with the indiscrete topology, and each has the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $A$ generated by that topology (which is just $\{\emptyset, \mathbb{N}\}$), then every function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is measurable. Let $f(n) = n$ for all $n$ and $g(n) = 0$ for all $n$; then $\{n : f(n) = g(n) \} = \{0\}$ is not in $A$.

We could replace $\mathbb{N}$ with any set that has two or more elements.

A more interesting question may be whether there is a counterexample with the additional property that the $\sigma$-algebras include all singletons. For example, can we make the underlying spaces $T_1$ or Hausdorff, and still form a counterexample with the Borel algebras of the spaces?